# Changing loaded data with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a document using D3 where the graph changes depending on what the user chooses and it works, however there is a problem with the data.

```
zivotni_broj;Datum;Kolicina_Vece;Kolicina_Jutro;fat;pro;lac;cels;sol;vlasnik
AA 110137783;3.6.2003 0:00:00;0,00;2100,00;5,21;3,70;4,44;,00;;00000001
AA 110137793;3.6.2003 0:00:00;0,00;1600,00;3,80;2,84;4,51;,00;;00000001
...
```

As you can see, it is in DSV format, however the data named "sol" is never recorded. I asked the source for the data and they said it means it's a zero, but D3 doesn't recognize it as a zero and the graph can't be drawn.

The data succesfully loads and I get an array of objects and I know how to change the nonexistent "sol" to a "0,00" value with a Javascript loop, but since I'm doing a presentation on D3 I want to do as much with the features D3 offers as I can. I'm reluctant to change the data since I want to show that D3 can work with pretty much any data, without needing to change the data file so it will work.

So my question is, does D3 have a way to loop through the data and change it without the need to change the original data file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a variation of Gerardo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45557495/4235784) you could use a *row conversion function* which is provided as the optional second argument to [dsv.parse(*string*, *[row]*)](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse). Since you asked for a D3 showcase this might be the closest you can get to an all-D3 solution.

```js
var dsv = 
`zivotni_broj;Datum;Kolicina_Vece;Kolicina_Jutro;fat;pro;lac;cels;sol;vlasnik
AA 110137783;3.6.2003 0:00:00;0,00;2100,00;5,21;3,70;4,44;,00;;00000001
AA 110137793;3.6.2003 0:00:00;0,00;1600,00;3,80;2,84;4,51;,00;;00000001`;
    
var parse = d3.dsvFormat(";").parse;
var data = parse(dsv, d => {   // Here the row conversion function is specified
  d.sol = "0,00";              // as an anonymous fat arrow function filling in
  return d;                    // the empty column sol.
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Please note, that this does exactly what you asked for, i.e. fill in `d.sol` with `"0,00"`, no more, no less. However, you are not restricted to this, you could do many more things like converting strings to numbers, filter or condense properties, introduce new properties and much more. You could even return a completely different object or an array built from scratch.

Comment: I ended up checking if the data is "" and turning it to "0,00" in the extent function since it basically loops through the data anyway and it works. The graphs the document draws rarely have more than 40-50 nodes so speed isn't an issue.

I tried your way as well and it works great, since I can also convert the date into a better format there and convert other data to float, thus cleaning up my code a little bit. However, the documents loads a bit slower in the beggining, but I can see where it makes sense if I'm showing large amounts of data at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

When D3 parses a DSV like yours, where some headers don't have a corresponding value, it simply creates a property whose value is an empty string.

Have a look here (`bar` is the empty one):

```js
var format = d3.dsvFormat(";")
var dsv = format.parse(d3.select("#dsv").text());

console.log(dsv)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="dsv">foo;bar;baz
12;;4
21;;5
17;;9</pre>
```

Therefore, to create the zeros, it's just a matter of looping the array:

```js
var format = d3.dsvFormat(";")
var dsv = format.parse(d3.select("#dsv").text());
dsv.forEach(function(d) {
  for (var key in d) {
    if (!d[key]) {
      d[key] = 0
    }
  }
})

console.log(dsv)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="dsv">foo;bar;baz
12;;4
21;;5
17;;9</pre>
```

EDIT: for a more idiomatic, D3 oriented answer, as [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552219/changing-loaded-data-with-d3/45557495#comment78075502_45557495), here is a demo using a *row function*:

```js
var format = d3.dsvFormat(";")
var dsv = format.parse(d3.select("#dsv").text(), function(d, i, columns) {
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    if (!d[columns[i]]) {
      d[columns[i]] = 0
    }
  }
  return d;
})

console.log(dsv)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="dsv">foo;bar;baz
12;;4
21;;5
17;;9</pre>
```

Comment: PS: Have in mind that the zero here is a real number, not a string, like the other values.

Comment: *"it simply creates a property whose value is an empty array"*—without having looked into it I am still pretty sure, it creates a null value not an empty array, right? As for the loop, I am a fan of the row conversion functions which also gives it more of a D3 touch just like OP asked for.

Comment: @altocumulus it doesn't create a `null` value, it creates an *empty string*, as you can see by yourself in the snippet... I don't know where was my mind when I typed "array", because I was thinking "string" (just edited the answer).

Comment: Regarding the row function, I never use it in my answers because the number of people that doesn't know that `d3.json` doesn't accept a row function is pretty huge. Therefore, I prefer to put the loop inside the callback: that way, it's safe to use regardless one has `d3.csv`, `d3.tsv`, `d3.json` or whatever function to load the data.

Comment: As I mentioned, I had not even tested it, I was just one step away from bed, but the array thing seemed so blatantly wrong... Anyways, as I still like my row conversion functions I posted my own take on it as an answer.

Comment: Damn, this question gives me headaches; or is it your speed ;-) When I started writing 3 hours ago you hadn't edited your post and there was no row conversion function in it. Unfortunately, I was interrupted and, when I eventually posted my answer, I did not recheck yours... Delete, keep, delete, keep... I am going to keep mine since there are some more extra bits of information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are more or less refering to the label? If so use the empty option inside the data object. See if that does the trick for you.

```
empty: { label: { text: "0,00" }   }
```